# Protect web API without identity server

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.1, openid-connect

In the current setup of an Asp.Net Core 2.1 web app and web api, I'm using IdentityServer4 as identity provider and I'm using IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation for protecting the web api (https://github.com/merijndejonge/OidcTemplate). 
I'm using the following configuration in the api:

```
        services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = domainSettings.Auth.Url;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.ApiName = domainSettings.Api.Id;
                options.ApiSecret = domainSettings.Api.Secret;
            });
```

While I'm perfectly happy with using IdentityServer4 as identity provider, I'm wondering if and how I can drop the dependency on IdentityServer in the web api, and use only functionality from Asp.Net Core itself. After all, I'm using OIDC, which should enable me to use different implementations at the identity provider and the web api side.

Can someone explain me how I have to change my web api setup, such that I connect with the IdentityServer identity provider without introducing a dependency on IdentityServer in my web api?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks for your comment. I rephrased my question a little bit.   What I want to achieve is to drop the dependency on a third-party library in my project and use only Asp.Net Core stuff for protecting my api. I think this is a pretty concrete and specific question.

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think these are valid arguments. Are you going to write your own version of other packages as well? The package is clean, netstandard2.0 without other dependencies. And it's open source. If you're curious, take a look at the source code. You can find it here: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation. And the used specifications: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/intro/specs.html. You can take the code and merge it in your own project. But you'll loose the benefits of updates and bug fixes.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg thanks again for your time to comment on my question. Please don't get me wrong, I love IdentityServer4. My question is whether its functionality to protect an API is still necessary in the API or can I do with plain ASP.NET core nowadays (since there is a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect namespace). We can also take this discussion offline if you prefer.